# Is there a compatibility issue between macros and Data validation written for Excel 1997-2003, 2007, 2010 and 2013?

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I have to do the validation in cells and at the sheet level using Excel's Data Validation and VBA which need to be compatible for excel 1997-2003 and above.

Some features which i need to include are disabling cells, adding a new field, deleting the cells, validation of entire sheet etc.

Comment: There are probably some *additions* in newer versions.. if you "need to to be compatible with Excel 1997", use Excel 1997.. *shudder*

Comment: There are multiple compatibility issues between that big count of versions. And there is [Compatibility Checker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg132972%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to check for. But at the end it is up to you to check the functionality in all versions which shall be supported.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will test it in all versions.